# I am looking for a post apocolyptic novel about a man and a female android

Tags: story-identification, androids

I believe the novel was printed by DelRey in the early eighties. I remember the protagonist was in love with a synthetic woman. He was trying to get more artificial blood for her. This one has been driving me crazy for years.

Comment: Can you add more details please? Anything at all, names you might remember, country(ies) it was set in, timeline it was set in, etc.

Comment: Can you confirm that the language is precise. Was she specifically referred to as a "synthetic woman"? Was he after "artificial blood"?

Comment: This sounds very similar to another question in here. Could it be 'World enough and time' by James Kahn? https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/145512/70s-80s-scifi-novel-set-in-california/159986#159986